# Replicating plugins in Vue Cypress component testing

Tags: vue.js, cypress

I am using Cypress to component test my Vue app. Following the code example at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/vue/examples#Replicating-Plugins produces several errors, listed below:

```
Argument of type '(this: Context, component: 
ComponentOptionsWithObjectProps<Readonly<ComponentPropsOptions<Data>>, unknown, {}, 
ComputedOptions, Record<string, Function>, ... 7 more ..., { ...; } | {}>, options?: 
MountingOptions<...> | undefined) => Chainable<...>' is not assignable to parameter of type 
'CommandFn<"mount">'.
  Type 'Chainable<{ wrapper: VueWrapper<ComponentPublicInstance<{ [x: number]: unknown; } & { 
readonly length?: number | Prop<unknown, unknown> | null | undefined; readonly concat?: 
Prop<unknown, unknown> | { (...items: ConcatArray<string>[]): string[]; (...items: (string | 
ConcatArray<...>)[]): string[]; } | null | undefin...' is not assignable to type 'void | 
Chainable<{ wrapper: 
VueWrapper<ComponentPublicInstance<ExtractPropTypes<Readonly<ComponentPropsOptions<Data>>>, 
unknown, {}, ComputedOptions, ... 6 more ..., {}>>; component: ComponentPublicInstance<...>; 
}>'. 

Property 'global' does not exist on type '[options?: MountingOptions<{ [x: number]: unknown; } 
& { readonly length?: number | Prop<unknown, unknown> | null | undefined; readonly concat?: 
Prop<unknown, unknown> | { (...items: ConcatArray<string>[]): string[]; (...items: (string | 
ConcatArray<...>)[]): string[]; } | null | undefined; ... 12 more ...; toLocale...'.

Cannot find name 'Vapp'.

No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
```

I am using TypeScript. Can someone please provide me with a working code snippet. My code is as follows:

```
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import i18n from "../../src/locales/i18n";
import { mount } from "cypress/vue";
import { h } from "vue";

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      mount: typeof mount;
    }
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add("mount", (component, ...args) => {
  args.global = args.global || {};
  args.global.plugins = args.global.plugins || [];
  args.global.plugins.push(createPinia());
  args.global.plugins.push(i18n);

  return mount(() => {
    return h(Vapp, {}, component)
  }, ...args);
});
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? And how would I call this mount function when used in tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone finding this questing, the answer of user14131782 makes that your agrs won't we passed down through. I followed the [Vue section of the Cypress docs on how to load Pinia stores](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/vue/examples), **they have an error**. After reading the Vue section of [API on the mount command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/mount) I found the sollution that also passes the args. So for any one ending up here, you can load your Pinia store in Cypress using this code, and it will also pass the args.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (component, options = {}) => {
  // Setup options object
  options.global = options.global || {}
  options.global.stubs = options.global.stubs || {}
  options.global.stubs['transition'] = false
  options.global.components = options.global.components || {}
  options.global.plugins = options.global.plugins || []

  /* Add any global plugins */
  options.global.plugins.push({
    install(app) {
      app.use(createPinia());
    },
  });

  return mount(component, options)
})
```

Comment: I did get around the args issue another way (can't remember how) but this is the best answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this using Vue Test Utils syntax. In /support/component.ts:

```
import { mount } from "cypress/vue";

Cypress.Commands.add("mount", (component) => {
  return mount(component, {
    global: {
      plugins: [createPinia(), i18n],
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: This works perfect for me, should be updated in the Cypress documentation. I tried but I need a Github account :(

Comment: it seems like this doesn't pass the args. I was playing around with ...args but I can't seem to get it to work. How do I include the args?